# Data at root level is invalid: Trying to deserialize json string

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization

I'm using Asp.Net, and although I've done some work deseriaizing Xml before, I've not got to do the same with json.

The error I'm getting is Data at root level is invalid, something I've seen before with Xml deserialization.

Here's the documentation I have for the response:

```
HTTP ResponseCode: 200
HTTP Status: OK
HTTP Body:
{
“Status”:”Success”,
“Response”:”0”,
“Price”:”10.00”,
“BuyerId”:999,
“BuyerContractId”:9999,
“Detail”:”https://...”
}
```

I'm using a WebClient to get the data back:

```
response = wc.UploadString(info.Endpoint, info.Data);
```

"response" is a string. I use this method to deserialize:

```
    public static T JsonResponse<T>(string response)
       where T : class
    {
        var s = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(response)))
        {
            return (T)s.ReadObject(r);
        }
    }
```

The class I'm trying to deserialize to is:

```
[DataContract]
public class ResponseProps
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Response")]
    public string Response { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "BuyerId")]
    public string BuyerId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "BuyerContractId")]
    public string BuyerContractId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Detail")]
    public string Detail { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how it's called:

```
var cr = XmlHelper.JsonResponse<ResponseProps>(response);
```

Anyone got any clues as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data comes in `JSON` format, I changed the following -

```
public static T JsonResponse<T>(string response)
   where T : class
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response);
    }
```

Now this works fine-

```
var q = JsonResponse<ResponseProps>('jsonString');
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that Amit, however it does involve another package. Have upvoted your answer though.